# Out of memory Heroku

Tags: scala, heroku, out-of-memory, playframework-2.3, pubnub

I'm running a 1 web dyno app on Heroku, Cedar stack. I'm seeing errors that I haven't seen while running locally.

After suggestions from *m-z and Geremy* (thank you so much!) ,and slightly modifying relevant code the OutOfMemory errors for pubnub are gone. Now I see the following.

```
Jan 28 02:09:41 peaceful-plains-5604 app/web.1:  [error] p.nettyException - Exception caught in Netty 
Jan 28 02:09:41 peaceful-plains-5604 app/web.1:  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread 
Jan 28 02:09:41 peaceful-plains-5604 heroku/router:  at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path="/api/question/6ddff" host=peaceful-plains-5604.herokuapp.com request_id=27490876-b9f6-40f8-a15f-4fbe0580cda5 fwd="202.174.120.2" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=503 bytes=0
```

**H13 heroku error code** suggests a timeout. My initial guess is that my method is taking too long to execute which is why Heroku is closing the connection.

I'll post the code of the method here.

```
def submitResponse(qkey:String) = CorsAction(parse.json){
    req =>
      val json = req.body
      ...//extract values from json request body...

      val currentKey = Cache.getAs[String](name).getOrElse("N_A")

      if(!currentKey.equals(key)){

        BadRequest("Inactive Key")
      }
      else {
        val response:Try[Response] = responseService.create(key,...)
        response match {
          case Failure(_) => {

            BadRequest("Duplicate " + key)
          }
          case Success(storedResponse) => {
            Ok(json)
          }


        }
      }

  }
```

The method `responseService.create` looks up a MongoDB collection for documents with  duplicate field, and inserts into that collection if no such document is found.

Question is: What are some of the quick wins here?
Possible solutions I can think of are 
1. Adding an index to the MongoDB document to make the lookup for a duplicate faster
2. Make the Controller end point Async?

**Im using a play framework 2 / Scala app.**

Would like to know

1. if I've correctly identified the root cause
2. what are things I can
       do to fix  this
3. Best practices and guidelines

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try `heroku config:set _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms256m -Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops" -a your-app-name` with the heroku toolbelt.

Comment: Currently my JAVA_OPTIONS are  JAVA_OPTS:                    -Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops. I need to add -Xms256m also? Thats the inital allocation - correct?

Comment: .. Did you try it exactly like "_JAVA_OPTIONS" ? Does the server print out that it picked up the options when starting?

Comment: PubNub is also on 3.7 at this point (https://github.com/pubnub/java), you may wish to upgrade your PubNub version while taking the memory configuration advice mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you both @m-z  . That helped fix that. But now to next question..

Comment: Have you recently updated to Cedar-14?

Comment: Not yet. @seigel. Should I?

Comment: Adding the indices definitely helped. Looking more into the OutOfMemory issue

Comment: @smk I had just read in the docs that "it may cause increased memory usage"  That is why I had asked. Also, are you using newrelic?  It sometimes is connected to memory issues.